# How to make a Uno Platform (for WA) that will work with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, webassembly, uno-platform

I am wondering, does Uno platform support WCF for WA?
and how I can subscribe and listen to the messages?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x It should generate the wrapper suitable for .NET Standard projects, which can then be used in your Uno projects.

Comment: Uno platform supports WCF. You can use WCF Services in uno platform projects. You only need to generate proxy classes according to the WSDL documents of WCF Services. In VS, Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider can help you complete this task. Then the WCF service can be called according to the generated proxy class.